Should I store the access and refresh tokens in cookies?
In my application, when the user logs in successfully, I generate the access and refresh tokens using JWT and store both in cookies. This seems correct to me because cookies add more security than local storage (by using HTTP only).
The problem is that both tokens are sent with every request. Theoretically, I should only send the refresh token when the access token has expired. Am I approaching this incorrectly?
The only solution I can think of is to store the access token in local storage and the refresh token in cookies (because it needs more security) , but I'm not entirely convinced by that. I am using Express and React. Is there something I haven't understood?
Thank you in advance.

What makes you think cookies are more secure than locale storage?

Because they can be configured as httpOnly, so they cannot be accessed with JS. Also with secure (to be used only with HTTPS), and a native expiration time can be added. With local storage, this cannot be done.

They (HttpOnly cookies) can still be read through other means though (ie. cURL, Postman, wireshark) so it's just security by obscurity.

cURL, Postman are clients, it should be able to read cookies anyway. Using Wireshark will not reveal the cookie details if the site is HTTPS, thanks to TLS (You may need a proxy like BurpSuite). The main concern of local storage is being able to access by JS.  It allows arbitrary JS code (XSS) to access tokens from local storage. Cookies also can be accessed from JS but making it httpOnly solves the issue. To avoid sending cookie to all paths, you can specify the intended path in path property.

What you can do to avoid refresh token being sent to every request is to ensure it is only sent to specific path, for example:
res.cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken, {
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true,
  sameSite: 'Strict',
  path: '/refresh-token' // this cookie will only be sent with requests /refresh-token
});

res.cookie('accessToken', accessToken, {
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true,
  sameSite: 'Strict'
});

